# meaning of "Dvd box set" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language

I am watching the show, 'Diners, drive-Ins and Dives' and I wonder one expression.

The show host, Guy Fieri said like below in on bakery eating a Cinnamon Pecan Roll.

> This is like **"Cinnamon Rolls Gone Wild."**
>
> **DVD box set.**
>
> Gooey, tender, nutty, cinnamonamony. It's outrageous.

I think it's a kind of humor or  figure of speech, but I don't know what it means. Could anybody help me, please?

Comment: Probably you need to know about [Girls Gone Wild (franchise)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girls_Gone_Wild_%28franchise%29), legendary in the US. My guess is that his phrase is a [take-off](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/take-off_1) ('6. copy someone for fun') on this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this episode, but Guy is referring to how good the cinnamon rolls are. He's referencing Girls Gone Wild, a franchise where people would go to college parties and film drunk girls taking their tops off as user3169 mentions in the comments. Probably more things go on in those videos, but I'm not going to get into details here.

A "DVD box set" is literally a collection of DVDs in a franchise that you can buy as a set. For example, you could get the [Star Wars Trilogy DVD box set](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Star-Wars-The-Original-Trilogy-A-New-Hope-The-Empire-Strikes-Back-Return-Of-The-Jedi-Blu-ray-DVD-Widescreen/27225025). DVD box sets often contain extra scenes, extended cuts, directory commentary, and are often advertised as limited edition. They can be better than just buying one movie at a time.

Guy is saying that if you had a DVD Box Set of Girls Gone Wild, it would be as good as having these cinnamon rolls. He's personifying the cinnamon rolls as the girls in the videos. So not only are they good, but he has a lot of them in a special set.